# how to output the difference of two floats as an interger in python

Tags: python

is there any way to output the difference between two float numbers as an integer

below is three examples of the float values provided for script, my goal is to output the difference between these values as an integer , in the first example i should get 2 where num_two - num_one equals 0.000002 but i don't want the zeros as they don't matter i can do it with string format but i have no way of telling how big the number is or how many zeros it has

```
## example 1
num_one = 0.000012
num_two = 0.000014

## example 2
num_0ne = 0.0123
num_tw0 = 0.013

## example 3
num_1 = 23.32
num_2 = 23.234


print (float(num_2) - float(num_1))

## this should output 86 as an integer
```

Comment: What is your limit for numbers after decimal digit , like if  we convert  after doing this operation **0.0000001-0.00000000001**, the result would be very large?

Comment: This looks like [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beware of floats (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754):

```
>>> 23.32 - 23.234
0.08599999999999852
```

You need exact precision. Use the [`decimal` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal):

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> n1 = Decimal("23.32")
>>> n2 = Decimal("23.234")
>>> n1, n2
(Decimal('23.32'), Decimal('23.234'))
>>> d = abs(n1-n2)
>>> d
Decimal('0.086')
```

Now, just shift the decimal point right (that is `* 10`) until there is no fractional part left (`d % 1 == 0`):

```
>>> while d % 1: 
...     d *= 10
```

(Don't be afraid, the loop will stop because you can't have more decimal levels than `decimal.getcontext().prec` at the beginning and the decimal level decrease on each iteration).

You get the expected result:

```
>>> d
Decimal('86.000')
>>> int(d)
86
```